# Understanding findWithinHorizon output

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

While *playing* with `Scanner` class, I wrote this little piece of code to see how `findWithinHorizon` behaves, however, I can't figure our exactly why some patterns are missing in the output.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        FileInputStream FS = new FileInputStream("dummy.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(FS);
        int counter = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            counter++;
            String P = scanner.findWithinHorizon(scanner.next(),100);
            if (P!=null)
                System.out.println(counter+" "+P);
        }
    }
}
```

And my `dummy.txt` file has this text:

> On her way she met a copy. The copy warned the Little Blind Text, that
>   where it came from it would have been rewritten a thousand times and
>   everything that was left from its origin would be the word "and" and
>   the Little Blind Text should turn around and return to its own, safe
>   country.

The code above prints out

```
2 her
3 e
4 from
5 its
```

that is clear enough. What I don't understand is that why the word ***copy*** is not in the output? Also, while trying to understand the mechanics of this method, I realized that horizon is actually number of characters (from Javadoc: no delimiters). But what about `scanner.next()`? Does it move the iterator to the next character or to the next word? If the former, how there are word (e.g. ***her***) is in the results?

Answer (score 0):

1) The reason why "copy" is not in there is because the `Scanner.findWithinHorizon()` also advances the token. 
See docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

" If the pattern is found the scanner advances past the input that matched and returns the string that matched the pattern."

Thus when "her" is found it skips beyond the original "copy" token.

2) `Scanner.next()` moves the iterator to the next token (as deliminated by " " by default).

3) "her" is found from w"her"e.

Comment: No attack, but I don't think your argument about `copy.` is valid. `findWithinHorizon` ignores delimiters. It is just like `her` and `where` as you correctly have mentioned.

Comment: I didn't exactly test it out but ill try to figure it out